# How to query schema statistics in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using Neo4j v2.2.3 community edition. I'd like to query the number of nodes by label and the number of relationships by type. I tried with:

```
MATCH (n:NODE_LABEL) RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT n)
```

and

```
MATCH ()-[r:REL_TYPE]-() RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT r)
```

While the first query is fairly fast (2.5s), the second query doesn't end after several minutes (there are ~100 million relationships of some types). However, according to [1] such info is kept by Neo4j. Thus, I'd have expected an immediate response for both cases. Is it possible to get this info in a different manner?

Thanks in advance!

[1] http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-schema-statistics.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about how the query planner works using the counts of relationship types, but you might try this somewhat simpler query:

```
MATCH ()-[r:REL_TYPE]->() RETURN COUNT(*)
```

Since there's no `DISTINCT`, the query planner might be more likely to use those statistics.  Also specifying the direction will make sure that relationships don't get counted twice (which is both wrong and likely slower)

But if you `PROFILE` this query, I suspect that it's going through every single node in the database and following the nodes out.  Neo4j keeps schema indexes by default for labels, but not for relationship types.  So if you happen to know that the relationship always starts with a node of a certain label (or labels), it would help Neo4j out by specifying that:

```
MATCH (:SomeLabel)-[r:REL_TYPE]->() RETURN COUNT(*)
```

or

```
MATCH (n)-[r:REL_TYPE]->()
WHERE n:SomeLabel OR n:SomeOtherLabel
RETURN COUNT(*)
```

Comment: Indeed, your suggestions (specify origin node label and relationship direction) yield a speedup but still is too slow for counting many relationships (~millions).